# ROR equivalent of Phoenix Mix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elixir, phoenix-framework

Mix command usage looks very similar to rails command. 
Are they the same, what are the differences & similarities?

Answer (score 4):

`mix` is the equivalent of several Ruby tools in one. `rake` is the task runner for Ruby (similar to gulp, grunt, make, etc. in other languages). You generally us it for things like running tests and builds. `bundler` is the idiomatic dependency management tool for Ruby. It downloads your dependencies and locks them for your project. `bundle gem` is commonly used for bootstrapping projects (like `mix new` I think)

Phoenix also integrates with `mix` and provides tools for starting your server (like `rails s`) and generating components (like `rails generate`). One that's a little weird is how you start up a debug shell (`iex -S mix phoenix.server` vs. `rails c`). The Elixir approach here requires you to start a server while rails doesn't (there's probably a way to do it without a server in Elixir, but I haven't figured it out yet)

In general Elixir seems to take the best ideas from a lot of popular Ruby libraries and gives them first-class support in the standard library for Elixir

I'd be happy to go into more detail about specific commands or features if you have questions about them

Comment: You can start the shell with code from your application, but without server using `iex -S mix`

Comment: Obligatory "year later" update - you don't need to start phoenix and the like in `iex` if you don't want to; you can just run `mix phoenix.server` (or `mix phx.server` for HEAD phoenix)